# Why didn't Chiaki wait a few more days?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-girl-who-leapt-through-time

In The Girl Who Leapt Through Time, Chiaki and Makoto talk at the end of the movie and he uses his last jump to return to the future. He asks Makoto to take care of the painting and find him in the future.

However, **why didn't he wait a bit longer to see the painting?** He'd been there for months, he could've stayed with Makoto and seen the painting himself.